# Bit Twiddling Hacks

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Can anyone help explain what does `val` stand for in the following example? I totally have no idea what is the value of `val`.

```
#define SPLAT(p)       (*(p) * (~0UL / 255))

uint8_t *page;
unsigned long val = SPLAT(page);
```

Comment: Why not just run the program?

Comment: `page` is an uninitialized pointer, so it is a mystery.

Comment: @Colin__s Sounds like a nitpick. I guess OP uses `page` just to emphasize that a macro argument must be a pointer.

Comment: Maybe, but the OP is asking for the value of `val` when we can't possibly say.

Comment: @Sergio It is however completely unclear why the macro must take a pointer and not just an 8 bit value. Or why a macro is used instead of a function.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it surely conceals its real nature a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that a `long` is 32 bits. The ~0UL is a bit pattern of all ones i.e. 0xffffffff. Now divide by 255 or 0xff giving 0x01010101.

Multiply this with an 8 bit quantity and you will get the same byte 4 times; e.g 0x5a * 0x01010101 = 0x5a5a5a5a.

This works independent of the size of a long, all bytes of the long are filled with the original byte.

For example with 8 byte longs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("%lx\n", (~0UL / 255));
    return 0;
}
```

gives as output:

```
8
101010101010101
```

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your reply. It seems that if sizeof(long)=8, this approach does not work.

Comment: Because if sizeof(long)=8, (~0UL / 255)=0x101010101015c20

Comment: This is strange, if a long is 8 bytes long you should get the same byte 8 times. (~0UL / 255) actually is 0x0101010101010101.

Answer (score 0):

- 'UL' to indicate an unsigned long constant
- (~) bitwise complement operator

Assume `sizeof(unsigned long)` = 4, then

```
~0UL = 0xffffffff, ~0UL / 255 = 0x01010101
```

Assume *(p) = 0x5a, then

```
0x5a * 0x01010101 = 0x5a5a5a5a
```